# How do you display SQLAlchemy database information on a html page (Python Flask)?

Tags: python, html, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been trying to create a gym's webpage in Python Flask for a college project but have encountered this issue. I am trying to display the the different memberships available for the gym (these are stored in a SQLAlchemy database) but I keep getting errors when trying to reference my database in the html file. I was told that the database was undefined, but when I tried to import it (using codeblock braces {% %}), I got this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'plan'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.
```

This is my current code for the html page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% from gymsite.models import Membership_plan %}
<form method="POST" action="">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Membership Plans:</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    {% plan = Membership_plan.query.filter_by(plan_name='18+ year') %}
     Plan name: {{ plan.plan_name }}
     Details: {{ plan.details }}
     Price: £{{ plan.price }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.membershipsub.label(class="form-control-label") }}
      {% if form.membershipsub.errors %}
        {{ form.membershipsub(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          {% for error in form.membershipsub.errors %}
          <span>{{ error }}</span>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
      {% else %}
      {{ form.membershipsub(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
      {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
  </div>
</form>



{% endblock content %}
```

This is my current code for the 'Membership_plan' table:

```
class Membership_plan(db.Model):
    plan_name = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    details = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    members = db.relationship('User', backref='member')
```

This is my route for this page:

```
@app.route("/memberships", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def memberships():
    form = MembershipsubForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        age18 = ['18+ year', '18+ 6 month', '18+ month']
        age15 = ['15-17 year', '15-17 6 month', '15-17 month']
        age10 = ['10-14 year', '10-14 6 month', '10-14 month']
        if not (current_user.is_authenticated):
            flash('You need to have an account to subscribe to a membership', 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
        elif (current_user.age >= 18) and (form.membershipsub.data not in age18):
            flash('You are not in the required age category to subscribe to this membership or this membership option is not available', 'danger')
            current_user.membership_plan = 'None'
            db.session.commit()
        elif (14 < current_user.age < 18) and (form.membershipsub.data not in age15):
            flash('You are not in the required age category to subscribe to this membership or this membership option is not available', 'danger')
            current_user.membership_plan = 'None'
            db.session.commit()
        elif (9 < current_user.age < 15 ) and (form.membershipsub.data not in age10):
            flash('You are not in the required age category to subscribe to this membership or this membership option is not available', 'danger')
            current_user.membership_plan = 'None'
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            current_user.membership_plan = form.membershipsub.data
            current_user.membership_expiration_date = membership_expiration()
            db.session.commit()
            flash('You have now subscribed to this membership!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('mymembership'))       
    return render_template('memberships.html', title='Memberships', form=form)
```

And the 'membershipsub' form:

```
class MembershipsubForm(FlaskForm):
    membershipsub = StringField('Which membership would you like to subscribe to?', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Subscribe')
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated and I can provide more of my code if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Try `{% set plan = Membership_plan.query.filter_by(plan_name='18+ year') %}` Although im not sure you can import code like that in a jinja template. Generally you run the query in the route and then pass the results to the template

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many problems, but I know there are 2 errors：
1、{% plan = Membership_plan.query.filter_by(plan_name='18+ year') %} cannot be placed in the html template，you should place it in the python file.
2、The table name should be added to the data table model

```
class Membership_plan(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tablename'
    plan_name = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    details = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    members = db.relationship('User', backref='member')
```